# Print out file lines with special characters - Linux

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, sed

I have a txt file with that is formatted like this:

`xxxxxxxxx,xxx`

with a few thousand lines.
I have this command right now to delete the special characters from the file 
`sed -i -e:a -e 's/[^0-9]\(.*,\)/\1/;ta' file.txt`

instead of editing the actual file, is there a way to print out the line of text that each individual one lies on?

I only need to test the first 9 characters as every line has a comma in it. :)

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: If you don't use the `-i` option, it prints the lines to standard output instead of writing them back to the file.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by `special characters`. No characters are special but they're not all treated literally in every context and you could be talking about punctuation chars, or regexp meta-chars or sed delimiters or any of a dozen other things when you say "special".

Comment: @EdMorton - special character are those that are neither a number nor a letter. Such as ([]{}<>.,/;:'"\|-_=+!@#$%^&*~`) but I really only care about (,./). Sorry I didn't clarify that a little better. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Oh, OK. Non-alphanumeric characters can be tested for by negating the `[:alnum:]` POSIX character class inside a bracket expression, e.g. `[^[:alnum:]]`. Now if you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output as @Cyrus asked for yesterday we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It SOUNDS like all you want is:

```
grep '[^[:alnum:]]' file
```

but without sample input/output we're just guessing.